# Asset routing error on Heroku after Rails 4 update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just updated my app to Rails 4.0.0.beta1 and Ruby 2.0.0.  It's a fairly simple app and the update went smoothly in development but when I deployed to Heroku I am getting a routing error on the precompiled assets.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-ec10cb548646d3f1c9963e6071fd834f.css"):
```

and

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/application-f6ecf7845034937996ac1e966af347b9.js"):
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: How are you precompiling?  Are you using asset-sync gem or precompiling locally first or....

Comment: I've had this app on Heroku for some time now, and it has always done an assets:precompile as part of 'git push heroku master' deployment process.  ctshryock answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you followed this guide ([Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4)) *before* yesterday afternoon (2013-03-27), then you likely need to change your Gemfile from:

```
group :heroku do
  gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
  gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
end
```

to simply:

```
gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'
```

Optionally, switch `:heroku` for `:production`.

Comment: didn't help me. still have the same issues. no fun.

Answer (score 14):

I believe this solution has been updated, and Heroku has replaced `rails_log_stdout` and `rails3_serve_static_assets` with `rails_12factor`. See [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4).

Now, you should put this in your GemFile:

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Then run `bundle install` and `git push heroku`.

Comment: Not just a belief, this is the solution!